# How does Dig Through Time work with Courser of Kruphix?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When [Courser of Kruphix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Courser%20of%20Kruphix) is on the battlefield and I resolve a [Dig Through Time](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dig%20Through%20Time), do I reveal the top card of my library AFTER I pick two cards from the seven I get to look at, or does the top card become revealed while I am looking at my seven cards?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting cards into your hand while the top of library is revealed](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/putting-cards-into-your-hand-while-the-top-of-library-is-revealed)

Comment: @Bret That question asks about whether the opponent should know whether the **current** top card goes into your hand. This question asks when the **next** top card is revealed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new top card is only revealed **after** you are done resolving Dig Through Time and the two cards are in your hand. This is because the cards you are looking at still count as being in your library while you are looking at them.